# VB.NET Calling BeginInvoke on another thread

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety, begininvoke

So from the comments section where this persons code was translated to VB.NET on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Threadsafe_formupdating.aspx it shows a little code to aid in calling cross thread UI stuff.

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function SafeInvoke(Of T As ISynchronizeInvoke, TResult)(ByRef isi As T, ByRef [call] As Func(Of T, TResult)) As TResult
    If isi.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim result As IAsyncResult = isi.BeginInvoke([call], New Object() {isi})
        Dim endResult As Object = isi.EndInvoke(result)
        Return DirectCast(endResult, TResult)
    Else
        Return [call](isi)
    End If
End Function
```

When I try to call the following however I get an error:

```
Me.SafeInvoke(Function(x) x.Close())
```

or

```
frmLobby.SafeInvoke(Function(x) x.Close())
```

Error   1   Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function SafeInvoke(Of TResult)(ByRef call As System.Func(Of frmLogin, TResult)) As TResult' defined in 'GvE.Globals' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.   C:\GvE\GvE\frmLogin.vb  37  9   GvE

What am I missing? I'm calling that code from inside a method defined in a form but that method is being called from another thread.

Just trying to avoid delegates and this is what the code above is supposed to do, but just can't get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: What version of VB.Net are you using?

Comment: 3.5

Sorry Mitch, what am I supposed to do? Is there some sort of accept answer button I'm supposed to click and does that give the person who answered some kind of prize? Sorry, I guess I just treated this like any other forum, but maybe I can go back and fix that.

Comment: @user441521: not prizes. But reputation. Think of it like saying "Thank you for the effort you put in to answering my question and helping me"

Comment: Went back to a few questions. I think I understand now. That grayed out check mark just never stood out to me before. This website is so busy visual wise. I'll go back and check the answers. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You shouldn't call `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`.  Instead, call `Invoke` if you want to wait for it to run, or just `BeginInvoke` if you don't want to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SafeInvoke` method takes a `Func(Of T, TResult)`.
That's a function that takes a `T` **and returns a `TResult`**.

Since `x.Close()` is a `Sub` and doesn't return anything, you can't make it into a `Func(Of T, TResult)`.

You should make an overload that takes an `Action(Of T)` – a sub that takes a `T` and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Cool thanks that worked (sort of). Showing the other form using this kind of works, but it hangs. I'll see what I can figure out.